# RSS Feed using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss

I create an RSS Feed using Codeigniter following tutorials from [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-rss-20-feed-with-codeigniter--net-7811)

but my problem is the feed content is not displaying on the page but available if you browse the html source.

here is my controller code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();        
    $this->load->model('articles_model');
    $this->load->helper('xml');
    $this->load->helper('text');
}

public function index()
{
    $data['feed_name'] = 'MyDebut.ph'; 
    $data['encoding'] = 'utf-8'; 
    $data['feed_url'] = 'http://www.mydebut.com/feeds'; 
    $data['page_description'] = 'Everything for turning 18.'; 
    $data['page_language'] = 'en-en'; 
    $data['creator_email'] = 'mydebutph@gmail.com'; 
    $data['posts'] = $this->articles_model->getArticlesPaginated(0,30); 


    header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    $this->load->view('rss', $data);
}
```

my view code:

```
    <?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . $encoding . '"?>' . "\n"; ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title><?php echo $feed_name; ?></title>
        <description><?php echo $page_description; ?></description>
        <link><?php echo $feed_url; ?></link>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
            <item>
              <title><?php echo xml_convert($post['art_title']); ?></title>
              <link><?php echo base_url().'blogs/'.$post['sec_slug'].'/'.$post['cat_slug'].'/'.$post['art_slug'];?>
              <description><?php echo character_limiter($post['art_sub'], 300); ?></description>
            </item>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

### View Buffer

Make sure you set the buffer(view as string) by passing true as the third parameter

---

```
$view = $this->load->view('rss', array('data'=>$data), true);
```

### Ouput Class

You can use the output class to send the buffer(not the view itself) directly to the browser

---

```
$this->output->set_content_type('application/rss+xml')->set_output(file_get_contents($view));
```

### Use Proper Meta attributes

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">
```

### Link to Xml Document

Add this to the `head` of the document. (only on blog page)

---

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss=xml" title="Blog Feed" href="<?php echo site_url('rss'); ?> "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is in your Model code but as far I can see in your controller you aren't getting the result array from the model. Check the 22 line of the rss view...

```
    <?php foreach($posts->result() as $post): ?>
```

Also check [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) documentation, maybe could help you